# Database schema for MCQ website/Quizzer

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin, relational-database

So I want to design a database schema for MCQ website in which I have several sections ,Lets say 3. and these section will have many sub-sections each.
I want to store the questions, choices and correct ans in such a way that every questions of sub-topics get stored in same table but questions of different section`s sub-section get stored in different one.

but,I don't know how to design a database schema like this. or what else could be better Approach ?

Comment: You probably _don't_ want to store the questions for the different sections in different tables.  It would be much more typical to have a column in your (single) questions table that stores the ID of the section for each question.  Then, when you want to fetch the questions for a given section, you'd `SELECT FROM questions WHERE section_id=X`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Possibly something like above? You have a section that can have as many questions associated as you want. Then a question that can associate with as many answers as you want. But the FK "answer_ID" under "Question" is a single "answer_ID" from the "Answers" table which tells you what the correct answer is. May not be the best but at least it would be a start. EDIT: the lines on the chart are wrong, sorry.

Comment: How can I store values in foreign key i.e. answer_id and question_id

Comment: Answers.Answer_ID to Questions.Answer_ID would be a ma y to one relationship. Meaning a question can only have one right answer. Then Questions question_Id to Answers.question_id is one to many as well. Meaning that a question can have as many possible answers as you want. But the only right answer is Questions.Answer_ID. The lines on my chart are wrong, sorry.